# what is the reason for increase in number of mis/sec in Redis, due to increase in user load

Tags: redis

The CPU utilization of redis server is around 11%, the mem used is 1.2 GB taken from redis stat, and fragmentation ratio is 1, and evicted keys count is '[mis/sec and hit/sec for diff user sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj87V.png)0'.
But the database operations by time consumed is high for redis-get, this is observed from newrelic. And the cache mis/sec are doubled for 25users to 65 users, i.e after increasing the user load.But the hits/sec got increased. So, what could be the reason for increase in mis/sec and what are factors that are to be considered?
And can we conclude that there is no problem with redis, by considering few parameters?

Comment: as mentioned in the question "few parameters", parameters like memory which is around 1.5gb, fragmentation ratio is 1, hit/sec is increased with increase in user load, evicted keys are '0'.

Comment: And how to identify the time taken by the individual query ?

Comment: As mentioned in the above question "few parameters" include rss_mem:1.2gb,evi keys:0, hits/sec- increased with 25-50 user load,cpu 11%.